# Create a new file, but add a number if the filename already exists

Tags: filenames

Is it possible to achieve this from the command line?

Syntax: I can capture an image with the following command:

```
raspistill -o image.jpg
```

But I want to be able to run this command via cron each minute and to get something like this

image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

num=1
outfile="image$num.jpg"

while [ -e "$outfile" ]; do
    num=$(( num + 1 ))
    outfile="image$num.jpg"
done

raspistill -o "$outfile"
```

The loop in the above script will increment the `num` variable by one and create a new output filename in `outfile` using this number, until a filename that is no taken is found.

This potentially fails if multiple copies of the script are run simultaneously, as there is a race condition between testing for the existence of the filename and creating the new file.  Running the script with a one minute interval should not be a problem unless it takes a minute or longer for `raspistill` to create the new file.  In this case, add `touch "$outname"` after the loop to "claim" the filename as soon as possible (simultaneous invocations of the script may still fail though).

By "failing" I mean two or more invocations of the script using the *same* filename with `raspistill`.

Comment: @Kusalanada thanks a lot! I'm a newbie in Linux and didn't know you can use a script in the command line, but how would that work? do I need to save it in a file, make it executable and run it with cron?

Comment: @Dante Yes exactly. If you save it in `~/script.sh` and make that executable, you can then schedule that script with `cron`.  This is simpler than trying to execute a complex command directly in the crontab file.

Comment: great, will give it a go!

Comment: @Dante If you want the script to create the files in a particular directory, you can `cd` to that directory at the start of the script, somewhere before the `while` loop.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind the suffix value as long as images are in ascending numerical order you could use the date and time

```
raspistill -o "$(date --utc +'image%Y%m%d%H%M.jpg')"
```

Extend with `%S` for seconds if needed.

If you do plan to add this as a one-liner remember that `%` is a special character in a `crontab` entry. Either sidestep the issue and put this in a (very short) script and call the script from `cron`, or precede each `%` with a backslash `\`. See `man 5 crontab` for the details (search for `%`).

Comment: Thanks! but I really wanted to be able to use the format in my question without the suffix

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I asked for a number at the end, not a datetime value.

Comment: Note that cron interprets `%` in a command specially.

Comment: @Kusalananda what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Dante See the end of the answer and read `man 5 crontab` about how `%` are treated in commands.